# Delete all lines from > to using regex in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How to delete all lines from `<recipe-banner` to `</recipe-banner>` in notepad++ using regex?

```
  <recipe-banner data-event-emmiter-ids="add-to-shopping-list-button add-to-shopping-list-handle-form">
    <core-sticky position="top">
      <core-conversion-teaser hide-on-close class="core-conversion-teaser--fixed-icon core-conversion-teaser--single-line" hidden="hidden">
        <div class="core-conversion-teaser__content">
          <span class="core-conversion-teaser__icon" aria-hidden="true">add_shopping_cart</span>
          <div class="core-conversion-teaser__message-section">
            <p class="core-conversion-teaser__header">Przepis został dodany do listy zakupów</p>
          </div>
          <div class="core-conversion-teaser__button-section">
            <a href="/shopping/pl" class="button--outline-primary">Pokaż listę zakupów</a>
          </div>
          <button class="core-conversion-teaser__close" aria-label="close"></button>
        </div>
      </core-conversion-teaser>
    </core-sticky>
  </recipe-banner>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it,

Find what: `\s+(<recipe-banner)[\s\S]+?(</recipe-banner>)`
Replace with: `$1>\n$2`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex as *"Find what"* in the *Replace* tab

```
<recipe-banner(.+?)</recipe-banner>
```

And leave the *"Replace with"* empty.

Make sure to enable *". matches newline"* in the search options